# Iterating over double 'for-each' function in javascript returning undefined when getting property from 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, console.log

This must be a stupid question, but I am not able to figure anything to do about it.

I have a simple HTML table with every  element having a property 'data-value'. I need to do some operations based on that, but one column at a time. Hence, I wrote a function which only runs on the first td element of each row. I am getting the rows by running another for each function.

When I use `console.log($(this))`, I am getting the expected td element from the all the first columns. Now, I want to store the 'data-value' property in another variable and do stuff on it.

```
  $(this).find('td:first-of-type').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    //returns td object
  })
});
```

As seen here, all the td elements are correctly being logged on console.

[image: correct working]

But when I use jquery to get the property 'data-value' from it, I get undefined.
[image: not working]

What could be the error ? Is this the best way to iterate every column's tds property  ?

```js
$('#table_canvas tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find('td:first-of-type').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    //returns td object
  })
});

$('#table_canvas tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find('td:first-of-type').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
    //returns tr object which does not have the 'data-value'property
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="table_canvas" class="table table--bordered" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>first_name</th>
      <th>is_staff</th>
      <th>last_name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th hello="hi">1</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>7</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your `td`s don't have `data-value` - "*//returns tr object"* - it's returning `undefined` in your snippet, not the `tr`.  Your snippet works fine if you change to `$(this).attr('data-property')`

Comment: @freedomn-m You are right. I knew there was a stupid error. But not this stupid :-x. You can post it as an answer if you want. Thank you for the other responses as well. Also, did my stupidity earn me the negative vote ?

Comment: It earnt you a close-as-typo vote :)

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Should I close this ticket ?

Answer (score 1):

its been awhile i dont use javascript but i think this is work for you vanilla js

just select every second child of every tr tag

```
document.querySelectorAll('#table_canvas tr td:nth-child(2)').forEach( x => {
    console.log(x.dataset.property);
})
```

Comment: look at his table he doesnt has data-value attribute so i assume he want to get the first td on the tr value

Comment: That's kind of my point - OPs using `$(this).attr('data-value')` and getting `undefined` - if he used `$(this).attr('data-property')` OPs could would work fine.  Doesn't diminish your contribution, just OPs question is a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to obtain the data, using vanilla JavaScript:

1. form array of `<tr>` elements
2. map tr array to array of td `data-property` values

```js
// array of <tr> elements
let trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#table_canvas tbody tr'));

// array of 'data-property' values
let props = trs.map(tr =>
  tr.querySelector('td').dataset.property);
console.log('props:', JSON.stringify(props));
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_canvas" class="table table--bordered" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>first_name</th>
      <th>is_staff</th>
      <th>last_name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th hello="hi">1</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>7</th>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
      <td data-property="True">True</td>
      <td data-property="1">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```